# Save Humanity Code in Hacker Rank

Tags: java, timeout, time-complexity

There is a problem under string domain in Hacker Rank, named as Save Humanity
with Link 
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/princetonolympics/challenges/save-humanity.

The are two strings given under the condition that if the two strings are equals its returns `true` and if there is a one-bit-error in the string then it returns true with the error indices.
Otherwise False for every other case.
My solution works fine for some test-cases,but for some test-cases the result is a timeout.

The question is how to decrease the Complexity.
For checking the one-bit-error I am using `charAt` function. Due to this the complexity rises.
Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to spam ? I found very difficult to read your question which is horribly messed with capital and small letters. Please format.

Comment: pls provide some code. otherwise this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Actually, I thought that the idea of places like hacker rank was that you improved your skills by solving the problems yourself ...

Comment: Please consider re-writing the problem, and show some code that you've tried (you mentioned you had code). It's very hard to provide help when we don't understand what you're trying to solve.

Comment: @ suresh atta Apologies for the previous Fromat. But how can you term it to Spam. Pls Refer a Dictionary.

Comment: And i have given the link for a Proper UnderStanding

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have two strings that you want to compare, but you want to accept them even if the they differ in one character.

This can be done in one loop by just comparing the strings byte by byte.

```
char[] a = "abc".toCharArray();
char[] b = "abb".toCharArray();
boolean oneDiff = false;
for (int i = 0; i<){
    if(a[i] != b[i]){
       if(oneDiff)
         return false;
       oneDiff = true;
    }
}
return true;
```

This has a time complexity of just O(n), which should be fast enough for most cases. If you need faster algorithms you can maybe research Edit Distance which is the name of this problem in the general case, but I don't think there are any faster algorithms.

Comment: you got the problem, but the when there is a string having 100000 characters then this solution is inefficient. My logic was same as this

Comment: It's really not. You are just iterating through the list once, which means that it has a O(n) running time. There is no way of solving this problem without going through the list at least once.

Even for small lists this method is quite fast, since all it does are a few array lookups.